# How to split data to pages in MS Excel using Java and Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I write to an excel sheet from my java program using poi api. when i have around 300 lines of data coming in from ms sql server, and i write to excel file using poi api, the data  is written but is continuous. I want something like, if row number is 70, go to the next page and write the data. the data in first 10 rows of all the pages is same. the data is written, but the first few common lines are not written. and i have set sheet.setautobreaks(true). still not working.
after row number 70, the data has to be written to new page in same sheet. with the first 10 lines in page 1 copied to page 2 and then the data from sql should be written. the data is getting written. but how do i write like start a new page if row number is 70?

Comment: `sheet.getLastRowNum();` use this, put a cap on it and create new sheets accordingly.

Comment: Could you please share your code and point to the not working part?

Comment: sorry, the system that has internet access, is isolated. i cant transfer my code to it.

Comment: i need new pages and not sheets

Comment: What are you doing to write those 10 repeating rows onm page 2, 3, 4 etc ?

Comment: sorry had not come to office yesterday. that is what my problem is. i am not able to write to pages. even if there are 100 records, all the data appears in one page only. i need to split data into pages if number of records is more than 70. don't know how to do it. please help me.

Comment: please help me i am struck